# Ceil function inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a function $x:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{N}$, Im sure that for small enough inputs I can bound this function but I dont know how to make a rigorous argument.

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and define

$$x(\epsilon):=\Big\lceil \frac{a}{\epsilon} \Big\rceil  $$

can I find an $\epsilon_0$ such that for all $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$

$$\epsilon x(\epsilon) \leq a~?$$

Comment: What have you tried? Have you worked with the definition of $\lceil \cdot \rceil$? What properties of this function do you know?

Comment: @leslietownes cant think to write anything other than $\epsilon x(\epsilon) = \epsilon k $ if $\frac{a}{\epsilon}\in(k-1,k]$

Comment: You could write $ceil(\frac{a}{\epsilon})=\frac{a}{\epsilon}+p$ for some $p \in [0,1)$. Then $\epsilon x(\epsilon)=a+p \epsilon$ and the desired inequality looks impossible from there.

Comment: @OliD Ok your right but I could choose $\epsilon$ small enough such that $\epsilon x(\epsilon)\leq 2a$. Right?

Comment: Absolutely you could, this appears to be true whenever $\epsilon < a$.